# Multiplication of powers of unlimited number of arguments. How can I refactor?

Tags: javascript, pow

```
function power(a, b, c, d) {
  return Math.pow(a, a) * Math.pow(b, b) * Math.pow(c, c) * Math.pow(d, d)
}
```

I'm wondering if there's a way refactor this using recursion? or maybe callback functions?

Comment: With sophistication? That's a matter of opinion, which is off-topic for StackOveflow. Anyway, I wouldn't be trying to complicate things with recursion when a simple loop over `arguments` (or `.reduce()` as shown below) will do it.

Comment: Unlimited number of arguments should be added as the requirement, I guess, to make the question non-off-topic.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=a) in combination with [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) as follows:

```js
function power(...args){
  return args.reduce((a, v) => a * Math.pow(v, v), 1);
}

console.log(power(1, 2, 3, 4)); // 27648
```

If the browsers you're targeting don't support rest parameters, you can fall back on the [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) object.

Also note that it won't take very high numbers to make the outcome overflow and yield a result of `Infinity`.

Comment: I would leave out your last part about overflowing. It might make some readers feel think that this isn't a feasible thing to do... This kind of operation makes sense with numbers in the range (0,1] (e.g. probability).

Answer (score 0):

**ES5** recursion version:

```
function power(){
  var arg = arguments[0];
  if(isNaN(parseFloat(arg)) || !isFinite(arg)) {
    return NaN;
  } 
  var pow = Math.pow(arg, arg);
  return arguments.length === 1 ? pow :
    pow * power.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
}

console.log(power(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)); // 4031078400000
```

**ES5** for-loop version:

```
function power() {
  var result = NaN;
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    var arg = arguments[i];
    if(isNaN(parseFloat(arg)) || !isFinite(arg)) {
      return NaN;
    }
    result = (result || 1) * Math.pow(arg, arg);
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(power(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)); // 4031078400000
```

I also included a protection from unwanted (non-numeric/infinite) parameters, so both of the functions return `NaN` if arguments are not not good.

Comment: You can use `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1)` though

Comment: Btw, the recursive `power` implementation will overflow the stack when you call it without arguments

Comment: @Bergi I believe, I finalized both of methods. Stack overflow should not occur :)